Генерация псевдослучайного числа генерирует повторяющиеся значения
Я использую свой класс Random для генерации чисел.
class Random {
    UInt128 seed;
    public Random(UInt128 seed) {
        this.seed = seed;
    }
    public int Next(int maxValue) {
        NextSeed();
        return (int)((seed * seed * 158 + 52185) % (UInt128)maxValue);
    }
    public void NextSeed() {
        seed = (seed * seed + 1856237) % UInt128.MaxValue;
    }
}

Затем через цикл for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) я генерирую эти случайные значения, и они разные. Однако при повторном вызове этого цикла генерируется тот же ряд чисел, хотя зерно должно быть другое, я его не переопределяю и использую один объект.
Вот для примера вывод рядов этих самых значений:
7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1
7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1
7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1
7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1
... // и т.д.

P.S. мне нужно использовать именно свой класс. И да, я знаю, что код ужасный, да и это приведение к UInt128 выглядит не очень хорошо.
Код тестирования:
Random random = new(27652582738);  // сид задан для примера
for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        Console.Write(random.Next(16).ToString() + " ");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}


С одним и тем же сидом будет одна и та же последовательность. А чем вас System.Random не устраивает? мне нужно использовать именно свой класс - почему? Код, которым тестируете, покажите.

@aepot Сид меняется. Я вызываю метод Next, а внутри него вызывается NextSeed, где сид меняется. System.Random не устроил тем, что я хочу в виде сида использовать UInt128, да и контролировать его изменение я тоже хочу сам.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что вас не интересует производительность этого генератора? Какой именно алгоритм вы пытались реализовать?

Запускаю ваш код, получаю в вывод 7 1 7 1 ... все строки одинаковые. То есть показанный в вопросе вывод в консоль не соответствует тестирующему коду.

@aepot Да, меня его производительность не интересует. Мне важно только то, что сид может быть 128-битным, и чтобы значения различных рядов не повторялись. Мне нужно генерировать ряды по 16 чисел, в числовом диапазоне 0-15. Но так, чтобы я мог при следующем запуске повторить эту же генерацию, введя этот же сид.

Окей, что за алгоритм пытаетесь реализовать? Не с нуля же вы код придумали, верно?

Извиняюсь, код немного поменял. Я просто вставил старые данные сюда. Код действительно выводит 7-1-7-1. Мне немного не ясна ваша формулировка. Я описал, что должен делать мой алгоритм чуть выше. Мне сейчас важно только то, чтобы не повторялись значения.

Вы код откуда-то взяли, верно? Это ГСПЧ, написанный по какому-то алгоритму, или в чём его смысл? Я не могу понять, как вам помочь, не понимая алгоритма. Отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы вывод в консоль совпадал с показанным кодом, а то непонятно, что лечить.

@aepot Хорошо, я вас понял. Это ГПСЧ, но писал я его сам, ниоткуда не брал. В моём понимании, в цикле должны выводиться случайные числа, а выводятся только 7-1-7-1.  Мне нужно решить как раз, как исправить эти повторения.

@aepot Он жалуется что если сделать UInt128 seed = 27652582738; и далее в цикле делать seed = (seed * seed + 1856237) % UInt128.MaxValue; то через некоторое количество итераций сид начинает повторяться и образует всего 2 варианта. И можно вообще оставить uint = uint * uint + число.

«Случайные числа не следует генерировать методом, выбранным наудачу. Не мешало бы использовать немного теории.» Начните, например, с линейного конгруэнтного метода.

@wololo То есть в данном случае вы мне советуете использовать не мои, а те константы, которые указаны на вики?

@MrLavoviy, надо использовать не только константы, но и указанную разрядность переменных, поскольку для получения правильной последовательности (не вырождающейся) важно, какие именно биты результата  останутся при переполнении (а оно всегда будет возможно при умножении самого на себя)

В этом коде 2 проблемы:

Переполнение, которое никак не контроллируется
Ошибки в математике

Вот например тот же код, который не страдает от переполнения
class Random
{
    UInt128 seed;
    public Random(UInt128 seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }
    public int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        NextSeed();
        return (int)(((BigInteger)seed * seed * 158 + 52185) % (BigInteger)maxValue);
    }
    public void NextSeed()
    {
        seed = (UInt128)(((BigInteger)seed * seed + 1856237) % (BigInteger)UInt128.MaxValue);
    }
}

Получаем такой вывод
7 9 7 7 1 1 7 9 1 9 7 7 7 1 1 9
7 7 1 7 7 9 9 7 1 7 1 1 1 1 7 7
7 7 7 9 7 1 1 7 7 1 9 7 7 9 7 9
7 1 7 7 1 7 9 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 7 1
7 9 7 7 7 9 7 7 7 7 7 1 7 1 7 7
7 7 7 1 1 1 1 9 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 7
7 1 7 7 7 1 1 7 7 7 7 7 1 7 7 1
...

Уже что-то более похоже на случайность. И видим, что во-первых все числа нечётные, во-вторых в последовательности участвует всего 3 разных числа.
Почему нечётные:
Вот у вас формула seed * seed * 158 где 158 - чётное число, а это значит что результатам этого умножения будет всегда чётное число. Следовательно если к нему прибавить нечётное 52185, то на выход пойдёт нечётное число. Следовательно, в выводе не может быть чётных чисел.
Почему всего 3 числа:
Вы игнорируете взятием остатка все биты, которые старше, чем ближайшая степень двойки к значению остатка слева. То есть всю энтропию, которую может дать эта формула вы попросту отбрасываете в сторону.
Ну и так далее. Выбранная формула просто не даст вам ожидаемого результата, собственно она и не является ГСПЧ.
Требование наличия 128-битного сида весьма странное и несовсем понятно, зачем. Хочется повозиться с хорошим ГСПЧ, вот вам реализация System.Random на базе алгоритма Xoshiro256. Есть альтернатива - более старый алгоритм ГСПЧ "Вихрь Мерсенна", вот реализация. Как видите, ГСПЧ с хорошим расперелением это немного больше, чем 2 строчки с умножением и взятием остатка. Поизучайте основные практики, каким образом производится приведение числа к пределу, заданному пользователем, и это не взятие остатка.
Другими словами ответ на ваш вопрос - взятие хорошего алгоритма и доработка его под свои нужды, чтобы он кушал 128-битный сид, только и всего. Или же поиск реализации, которая уже поддерживает 128-битный сид из коробки.

Вот, попробовал избавиться от отбрасывания бит из-за взятия остатка и заменил 158 на простое число 157, а 52185 на ближайшее простое число 52189.
class Random
{
    UInt128 seed;
    public Random(UInt128 seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }
    public int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        NextSeed();
        return (int)(((BigInteger)seed * seed * 157 + 52189) % UInt128.MaxValue * maxValue / ((BigInteger)UInt128.MaxValue + 1));
    }
    public void NextSeed()
    {
        seed = (UInt128)(((BigInteger)seed * seed + 1856237) % (BigInteger)UInt128.MaxValue);
    }
}

Получил вывод
0 9 15 12 11 5 15 1 13 12 15 8 3 7 5 10
8 6 13 6 11 2 15 0 12 15 10 6 9 7 13 2
11 15 5 4 6 1 10 7 8 9 2 11 7 8 13 8
9 4 4 1 15 11 9 0 1 8 6 13 1 6 7 2
3 5 13 9 6 2 14 4 10 14 9 2 4 15 15 13
5 2 9 9 5 2 15 8 9 0 10 4 7 1 1 3
0 13 5 0 5 13 8 14 6 1 11 11 12 12 15 5
0 13 6 15 4 12 2 4 6 14 7 14 2 13 14 12
5 8 6 14 9 11 12 14 2 3 0 4 5 4 10 5
8 0 8 14 15 10 6 1 11 11 5 5 11 12 6 11
...

Согласитесь, что так гораздо лучше? Но этот код всё равно пока что не претендует на ГСПЧ.

@MrLavoviy ссылочку на Вихрь откройте и обратите внимание на метод public int Next(int maxValue), там показано, как сгенерированное число приводится к лимиту, заданному пользователем. Там Uint32, вам на 128 заменить, ну и через BigInteger вычислить. Должно получиться что-то более вменяемое, чем взятие остатка.

@MrLavoviy дополнил ответ.

Спасибо за дополнение. Я немного теории почитал. То, что у вас в конце получилось - линейный конгруэнтный метод, получается? Только с верными константами? И у меня остался вопрос по переполнению. Переполнение из-за чего возникает? Из-за максимальных значений UInt128? Я ведь в конце использовал остаток для ограничения.

@MrLavoviy для простоты представьте byte 0-255. Что будет, если к примеру 16 * 17? Число больше, чем 255. Это и есть переполнение.

То есть тут вопрос в памяти, а не в самом типе данных? Получается, условное byte b = (16*17) % 256; будет переполнением?

@MrLavoviy конечно будет, потому что в процессе умножения будет переполненный byte. Ведь компьютер последовательно выполняет математические операции, верно? Наведите мышь на знак умножения, будет подсказка, для каких типов выполняется вычисление. И если результат не влезает в тип, то это переполнение.

Не бороться с переполнением для алгоритмов ГПСЧ это нормально. Они все заточены на переполнение при умножении

@avp я согласен, что это нормально, если переполнение контроллируемое. То есть когда получаем ожидаемое поведение при переполнении, используем unchecked и т. д. А не когда мы написали код, он как-то работает и при непонятно, что получится при переполнении.

Ну, да. Это же шарп, а не чистый Си
